# replicate modification from Devstack to Openstack (production)

Tags: python, openstack

I installed openstack through DevStack because I had to modify some files.
When I install DevStack, I have all the files under /opt/stack.  There I have services folders (glance, keystone...) and libraries folders (python-glanceclient, python-keystoneclient).
If I modify those files, how can I replicate modification on a already deployed Openstack? Installing openstack without devstack builds a different structure of folder.

I mean, where the python-'service'client folders are in a fresh openstack installation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

devstack pulls it's openstack software stack from github.  the git repot's it installs from are located in /opt/stack.

What you may want to do is fork openstack as well as the repot of the openstack projects you wish to modify, then make your devstack deployment deploy not from the openstack repot, but your own forked repot.

you can do this by modifying the stack.sh script ( I believe ).   devstack.org has a line by line explanation of the entire script on their site and that can point you in the right direction.

http://devstack.org/stack.sh.html  read this.

once you've deployed using your own git repository you can of course edit and commit back to it.  even push to it.

then any other devstack deployment you have can also be setup to pull from your repository instead of the public openstack repos.

of course rebasing later against openstack will be increasingly difficult as openstack developement moves at a fairly brisk pace.

If the modification you are making is one you want to commit back to the open source project check out this site:

http://wiki.openstack.org/HowToContribute

Basically openstack has a commit review and continuous integration environment that is based off of gerrit and jenkins.  This is the method by which commits back to the open source repository are gate tested and manually reviewed by other developers before being merged.

If you are intending to deploy this for production use, I recommend against deploying from devstack.  This is not the proper way to do that.

Comment: The problem is that I should replicate my modification in an already-in-use openstack installation.  I don't want to commit them to the community because it's a custom version for my specific needs.

Comment: You may want to commit back to your own forked repository from your devstack as I discussed early.  Then deploy to your systems using a packaging system.  You can look at the source packages for ubuntu or redhat to get an idea of what you need to do to do that.  But that's a whole different discussion.

Comment: Do you think this can be the solution also for already installed systems? I hope I could be something simpler..

Comment: Actually packaging from source is a pain atm.  The clients for instance require access to their git repositories to figure out and set their internal version.  Without it they set to 0.0.0 and explode catastrophically.  You can work around this ( mostly ) by placing your own versioninfo file.  But there are other pains as well.  Currently what you want to do is pretty hard.  Maybe do a post install patch via chef/puppet/config management.  Or a patch via a follow up package.

Comment: mm... maybe I found a way.  I saw that if I copy a folder from DevStack to OpenStack and run the setup, the modified files affect the installation. I mean..   for example i modify files in "nova". I copy the folder "nova" somewhere in the machine with openstack, run "python setup.py install", and modification are auto-installed. I have not tested it well yer, but seems work

Comment: That's fairly unsafe.  Those directories likely have had setup.py ran on them already.  So they are "dirty".  I do not recommend doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you give me more details about the unsafety of the action, please?  I don't understand very well what setup.py does...  Does it replace modified files in .../python2.7/disk-packages/...  ?